# nonlinear ode to linear ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Assume the ODE

$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y)
$$

Suppose $f$ is non linear. Is it possible that a change of parameterisation and a change of variables provide a linear right hand side ?

Let 
$$
y = \phi(z)
$$
then the resulting ODE is
$$
\dot z = \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}(z)\right]^{-1} f(\phi(z))
$$

Now what if we take $\phi\in C^1$ diffeomorphism satisfying
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} = f
$$

that is $\phi$ is a primitive of $f$ ...

Comment: Your $\phi$ should satisfy the differential equation $\frac{d\phi}{dz} = f(\phi(z))$, but this is exactly the first differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y(t))$.

Comment: @Smilia : $\frac{dy}{f(y)}=dt$ is linear on the right hand side. Just integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your intention to make it linear, but I will say that unless $f$ is $C^0$ and initial value condition $f(y(0))\neq 0$, then you will have some open interval $I$ containing $0$ with exact solution $y'(t)=f(y(t))$. So to find a solution you will not need any linearity.